# How to deal with R packages from CRAN which are more recently built than Anaconda's Jupyter library?

Tags: r, jupyter, cran

There are answered questions for how to install R packages which do not come in the *r-essentials* build for Jupyter. But the R version which comes with Anaconda Jupyter is sometimes back a level from the most recent at CRAN.

The trouble is that when packages outside of *r-essentials* are loaded, a warning is issued that the packages have been built with an R version which is more recent than that installed.  Installation continues, but there clearly is the risk that because of the version skew between the packages and the R version, something could go wrong during execution.

Is there an always up-to-date *r-essentials* some place which can be used with Anaconda Jupyter?

This is for Windows 7, and R version 3.4.3.

Comment: FWIW those messages can be safely ignored 99.9% of the time when you're in-series (i.e. 3.4.x).

Comment: @hrbrmstr True.  I do wish CRAN/R had a better way of dealing with versioning (by default) though.

Comment: The versioning is great IMO. You can always install from source (perma-archive) and the default to net-new upon R version release. But I also run a CRAN mirror at home and maintain my own home pkg mini-CRAN so I'm likely very biased :-)